# How to bind the Command to its "TemplatedParent"

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

How to bind the Command of the Button "myCmdButton" to the ParameterVariableList, like the "addBtn" do.
The "addBtn" works like expected.
I want the other button command to my ParameterVariableList class too.

Here's the XAML:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type locale:ParameterVariableList}" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
        <Button Content="add" Command="{Binding AddEntryCmd}" Name="addBtn" />

        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <ItemContainerTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />

                        <Button Width="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Command="{Binding RemoveEntryCmd, ???}" Name="myCmdButton" >
                            <Image Source="Resources/trash_16x16.png" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Button>

                    </StackPanel>
                </ItemContainerTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

I expected this to work, but it doesn't:

```
Command="{Binding RemoveEntryCmd, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type locale:ParameterVariableList}}}"
```

Error: 
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='hmi.ParameterVariableList', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=RemoveEntryCmd; DataItem=null; target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
Command="{Binding DataContext.RemoveEntryCmd, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}"
```

Nearly the answer of Abhinav, but DataContext was missing.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
Command="{Binding RemoveEntryCmd,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}
```

Comment: No. System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'RemoveEntryCmd' property not found on 'object' ''ListBox' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=RemoveEntryCmd; DataItem='ListBox' (Name=''); target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand') .. tried AncestorType x:Type locale:ParamaterVariableList too .. dont work ..

Comment: Sorry.The Ancestor Type should be the parent Type control used by DataTemplate.

Eg.If the parent of Data Template is datagrid then Datagrid should be theAncestor Type.

Comment: The parent of that DataTemplate is a ListView, but same Errormessage: System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'RemoveEntryCmd' property not found on 'object' ''ListView' (Name='listview_settings')'. BindingExpression:Path=RemoveEntryCmd; DataItem='ListView' (Name='listview_settings'); target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand') .. Thats even not logical for me, cause its NOT the Property of that ListView ?

Comment: Does your RemoveEntryCmd is working?? Have you tested the command outside the template.

Comment: Replaced AddEntryCmd with RemoveEntryCmd and its executed!